# symfony 1.4 not picking up subdirectory in routing?

Tags: symfony-1.4

I have one symfony 1.4 project where I can happily access the symfony app in a subdirectory www.olddomain.com/clients/

I have tried to achieve the same with another seperate project. 
www.newdomain.com/clients/ but the routing won't work fully. 
I can access www.newdomain.com/clients/ and it picks up the app and displays the login or content as it should BUT the login form submits to /login, NOT /clients/login as happens with the www.olddomain.com/clients/ project

, I have compared the two and cannot see any difference in the setup.

I have set the WebDir:

```
$this->setWebDir($this->getRootDir().'/content/clients/');
```

no_script_name is set to true

I have everything that would be in the web root (index.php, .htaccess, css js etc in /clients/.)

.htaccess in both cases contains

```
RewriteBase /clients/
```

If I access www.newdomain.com/clients/login it picks up the need to show the login form fine so that indicates my setup is OK BUT the login form which points to route @login is submitting the form to "/login" not "/clients/login".

I've tried dumping the route on both projects when I directly access /clients/login (see below) and have noticed that on the one that works there are a lot more variables in the 'context' including [ prefix: '/clients'] which would seem to be the key. All of this extra context information except the host variable is missing for www.newdomain.com/clients/login.

Can anyone help me understand what this means and how I might address it? How can I get this 'prefix' paramater set.

DOES WORK (www.olddomain.com/clients/login)

```
object(sfRoute)[31]
protected 'isBound' => boolean true
protected 'context' => 
array
  'path_info' => string '/login' (length=6)
  'prefix' => string '/clients' (length=8)
  'method' => string 'GET' (length=3)
  'format' => null
  'host' => string 'www.olddomain.com' 
  'is_secure' => boolean false
  'request_uri' => string 'http:/www.olddomain.com/clients/login' 
 protected 'parameters' => 
array
  'module' => string 'sfGuardAuth' (length=11)
........
```

DOESN'T WORK (www.newdomain.com/clients/login)

```
object(sfRoute)[47]
 protected 'isBound' => boolean true
  protected 'context' => 
array
      'host' => string 'www.newdomain.com' 
protected 'parameters' => 
array
  'module' => string 'sfGuardAuth' (length=11)
```

.....

Comment: "I have one symfony 1.4 project running happily in a subdirectory", are you saying you are trying to leverage the code base from client1 directory to work with client2 directory? If so, I think you need to configure your vhost configs, as apache(?) will send all requests to docroot, but then to try to serve from another directory won't work.

Comment: sorry for lack of clarity, I have edited the question. This is 2 totally seperate projects One where it works one where it doesn't despite an apparently identical setup except the fact that the one that doesn't work uses doctrine and the other propel which I don't see that that should make any difference?

Comment: Solved the issue. It was my mistake. In the factories.yml file in newdomain.com/app/frontend/config/ I had a routing definition containing:
      context:
        host: www.newdomain.com

it appears that doing this overwrites everything else thus removing prefix etc. wll be asking a seperate question about how to avoid this overwriting.